# Yes or no questions and looping

Tags: java, list, arraylist, do-while

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReminderYen {
    private String constant;

    public String getConstant() {
        return constant;
    }


    public void setConstant(String constant) {
        this.constant = constant;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
       List<ReminderYen> reminderList = new ArrayList<ReminderYen>();
       char j;

       do
       {
           ReminderYen constant = new ReminderYen();
           System.out.println("Enter your reminder: ");
           constant.setConstant(input.next());

           reminderList.add(constant);

           System.out.println("Would you like to enter a new reminder (y/n)? ");
           String answer = input.next();
           j=answer.charAt(0);
           if(j=='y');
           System.out.println("Enter your reminder: ");
           constant.setConstant(input.next());

           System.out.println("Would you like to clear all your reminders (y/n)? ");
           if(j=='y');
           String ans = input.next();
           j=ans.charAt(0);
       }
       while(j== 'y');
       System.out.println("Your reminders are: ");
       for(ReminderYen c : reminderList){
           System.out.println(c . getConstant());
       }
    }
}
```

First, I want to display "enter your reminder: " after I enter the reminder, it would display "would you like to enter a new reminder (y/n)?". If "y", it would display again "enter your reminder: "; if "n", it would display "would you like to clear all your reminders (y/n)?"; if "y" it would display again "enter your reminder:" and it will clear all the reminders; if "n" it would display all the reminders that he/she entered.

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: What is your problem?  Ask exactly what you are looking for ?

Comment: And suspicion falls to `if (j == 'y');`  <--- And what `;` will do when it appears here

Comment: When I enter the reminder then it would display "would you like to enter a new reminder(y/n)?" i  will enter "y" then it will display "enter your reminder when i enter "n" it cannot display the "would you like to clear all your reminders(y/n)?"

Answer (score 0):

This is the empty `if`:

```
 if(j=='y');
```

All you want to do under the `if` statement should be inside the curly brakes:

```
 if(j=='y') {
       System.out.println("Enter your reminder: ");
       constant.setConstant(input.next());
}
```

You are trying also to compare the input before you're actually got it:

```
   System.out.println("Would you like to clear all your reminders (y/n)? ");
       if(j=='y');
```

Also, all code inside the loop will run each time. If you want something to be executed only once at the end - you should put it *after* the loop.
I guess you want something like that:

```
ReminderYen constant = new ReminderYen(); 
System.out.println("Enter your reminder: "); 
constant.setConstant(input.next()); 
reminderList.add(constant); 

while (j=='y') { 
    System.out.println("Would you like to enter a new reminder (y/n)? "); 
    String answer = input.next(); 
    j=answer.charAt(0); 
    if(j=='y') { 
        System.out.println("Enter your reminder: "); 
        constant.setConstant(input.next()); 
        reminderList.add(constant); 
    }
   else if (j == 'n') {
     System.out.println("Would you like to clear all your reminders (y/n)? "); 
     String ans = input.next(); 
     j=ans.charAt(0);
     if(j=='y') {
         // clear the reminders here
     }
}

System.out.println("Your reminders are: "); 
for(ReminderYen c : reminderList){ 
    System.out.println(c.getConstant()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first understand the significance of semi colon in Java. In Java semicolon depicts the end of the statement. The semicolon you have placed at the end of if statement and while statement signifies the condition/loop has ended without actually doing anything. Whatever you want to do under the if statement should come under the curly braces.

```
if(j=='y') {
       System.out.println("Enter your reminder: ");
       constant.setConstant(input.next());
}
```

Similarly for while loop

```
while(j== 'y') {
   System.out.println("Your reminders are: ");
   for(ReminderYen c : reminderList){
       System.out.println(c . getConstant());
   }
}
```

Try to go through basics of Java, looping, conditional statement before you start coding. It would help you.